# A book about a space trader. Starts in a graveyard city of an ancient civilization looking for valuable relics. Finds one; is almost murdered

Tags: story-identification, novel

A book about a space trader. Starts in a graveyard city of an ancient civilization looking for valuable relics.

He escapes with a valuable artefact. Has great dedicated crew. Meets a godlike woman on a stop at a hollowed-out asteroid. Colorful character. Takes an order for the most popular liquor in the universe, goes to planet where it is made, falls in love with daughter of guy who makes it, and returns with 40,000 cases of it. In the end, he returns to the girl who's had his child. Maybe a series.

I read it about five years ago but it may have been published before that.

Comment: Was it a paper book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: Much of that matches MCU's Guardians of the Galaxy!  (not a serious suggestion)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is Peter F Hamilton's [Night's Dawn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night%27s_Dawn_Trilogy) trilogy.

It's large scope space opera with multiple interweaving storylines, and the one you recall is centred on Joshua Calvert. He initially lives in a sentient habitat called 'Tranquillity', scavenging alien remains. Having found a valuable relic, he uses the cash to repair the ship the 'Lady Macbeth', recruit a crew, and go to work as a trader.

The drink referred to is 'Norfolk Tears', very rare and expensive. He ends up with a large supply by being alert to what one of the families really want, and ends up staying at their home where he has an illicit relationship with the teenage daughter, Louise Kavanagh.

She discovers that she is pregnant after he leaves, but they do meet up again at the end, after dealing with the dead possessing the living, and travelling about a quarter of the way around the galaxy.

A great read, but not a small one!